# While working in angular 13, for "HTMLCanvasElement" and "CanvasRenderingContext2D" I am getting "Object is possibly undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

While working in angular 13, for "HTMLCanvasElement" and "CanvasRenderingContext2D" I am getting

> Object is possibly undefined

Code snippet:

```
canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement | undefined ;
    
private plot: CanvasRenderingContext2D | undefined;

....
....

//following all lines giving error of "Object is possibly undefined"
this.canvasEl = this.canvas.nativeElement;
this.plot=this.canvasEl.getContext("2d");   
this.canvasEl.width = this.width;
this.canvasEl.height = this.height;
```

How to resolve these errors? How I can declare variables to solve these errors?

Comment: Your typedefinition indicates that the two variables are possible undefined. This is indicated by this part " | undefined". Basically you´re telling ts, that the variable can be undefined. If you don't check for undefined, the value is possible undefined. Thats what it tells you. If you check for undefined, the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your element is available and never undefined just add a ! after your variable:

```
canvasEl!: HTMLCanvasElement 
private plot!: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
```